# Resources for bioinformatics or computational biology

Tags: text, reference-request, education

I am looking for some textbooks/websites to learn applications of Mathematica to bioinformatics/computational biology. Searching on Amazon and Wolfram books section did not result in any direct hits. If someone has used any books using Python / R and know that those examples could work well in Mathematica framework, please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: did you see the [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Wolfram Solutions: [Bioinformatics](https://www.wolfram.com/solutions/industry/bioinformatics/)
- Book: [Illustrating Evolutionary Computation with Mathematica](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BCRB6JO)
- Docs: [Life Sciences & Medicine: Data & Computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LifeSciencesAndMedicineDataAndComputation.html)
- Wolfram Demonstrations: [Biology](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Biology&limit=20)
- Wolfram Demonstrations: [Genetics](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=genetics)
- Wolfram Books: [Life Sciences](http://www.wolfram.com/books/topics.html?topic=%22Life%20Sciences%22)
- Mathematica Journal: [Biology](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/?s=biology&x=0&y=0)
- Library: [Bioinformatics](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/Science/Bioinformatics/)
- Library: [Biology](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/Science/Biology/)